# Pay someone vs Pay to someone

Tags: prepositions, comparison, objects

I know we don't use "Pay to someone," but is there a reason?  In terms of grammar, it seems correct.

Pay (transitive verb) + someone (direct object)
Pay (intransitive verb) + to someone (prepositional phrase)

We say "Climb the mountain," and "Climb up the mountain" both.

Why don't we use "Pay someone," and "Pay to someone" both?

*I am asking this question because there may be something I don't know that may help improve my English.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb "pay" can have two objects.  Perhaps called *direct object* and *indirect object* in some descriptions.  But you are not required to use both.

You can say "Pay Tom $5".
You can say "Pay Tom."
You can say "Pay $5."
You can say "Pay."
Do not say "Pay $5 Tom."

But use the "to" instead of the indirect object usually *after* the direct object:
You can say "Pay $5 to Tom."
Perhaps you could say "Pay to Tom $5," but that would be unusual.

I guess if the $5 is replaced by something long and complicated, then it is OK:
"Pay to Tom the amount you would have paid if he were not your brother-in-law."

Answer (score 1):

*Pay* is a ditransitive verb like *give* and *offer*, so it takes two common arrangements of arguments.

> John gave the book to Jane. Jane paid £5 to John

> John gave Jane the book. Jane paid John £5.

But unlike *give*, we are not necessarily concerned with the direct object (the amount), and so we can omit it.

> Jane paid John.

*Show* works the same way: even though what is being shown is important, we can omit it when it has already been mentioned:

> Jane showed Helen [the picture].

But with *give* we cannot omit the direct object even if it has already been mentioned:

> *John gave Jane.

> *John gave to Jane.

are both ungrammatical. We have to say

> John gave it to Jane.

Oddly, you can turn this round, but only if you use a pronoun for the recipient:

> John gave her it.

but

> ?John gave Jane it.

is not acceptable to most English speakers.